# Flutter BLoC: Combine more than 9 streams

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart

I'm using Flutter and RxDart. I have a large form, which unfortunately it can only be in one page(widget). In the past I've used CombineLatestStream, but now I have at least 18 numeric fields:

```
Stream<bool> get validateLargeFormStream => CombineLatestStream.combine9(...
```

Is there a way to combine all my streams to validate them? (Check if length is more than 1)

Answer (score 0):

`Rx.combineLatest<T, R>` takes an iterable of Stream

```
Stream<bool> isValid$ = Rx.combineLatest([
  stream1,
  stream2,
  ...
], (values) => values.every((element) => element == true));
```